# Can I update the Software Center to 4.0?

Tags: 10.10, software-center, updates

Is it possible to update the **Ubuntu software center** in maverick to **4.0** ?

I have tried adding `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main` to software sources but installation failed (lot's of version problems)

Comment: If they is a **GTK 2.x** version of **software center 5.0** for maverick, I am also interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to update Software Center via the official repositories.

I don't believe that you will be able to use version 4 of the Software Center in maverick.  It hasnt been backported.

The [software store developers](https://launchpad.net/~software-store-developers/+archive/daily-build?field.series_filter=maverick) produce a daily build - as the name suggests, its not tested, but contains the latest changes on a day-to-day basis.  However, I dont see any evidence that that has built successfully for sometime.

I would contact the software-center developers themselves (file a bug report via that link) if there was any intention to have version 4 available for maverick.  Its probable that it is just a recipe build packaging mistake by the maintainer Michael Vogt.

Comment: danjjl - I've rowed back on this answer.  See my revised advice.

Comment: I quite like it :)

Answer (score 0):

PPA with USC daily builds -- https://launchpad.net/~software-store-developers/+archive/daily-build

Actual version for Maverick is *4.1.20~bzr2217*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This ppa doesn’t a 64bit package (and for the moment the 32bit one is broken)